# What short film features a space station that projects movies onto the moon?

Tags: story-identification, space, short-film

I'm looking for a short indie film where a space station orbiting the moon has a giant lens that projects movies onto the moon. I may have seen it on io9, but I'm not sure.

It begins with a guy walking down a hall. He sits at a terminal and starts using the controls. A wall panel opens, revealing a film projector. The giant lens on the bottom of the station turns on, projecting old black-and-white movies (maybe Charlie Chaplin). Large doors open, showing an audience which watches the movie.

Comment: That's very little to go on. Do you remember nothing else? What kind of movies were projected (commercials? feature films? political propaganda?)? What was the purpose of the projection? Who watched it? Were there any remarkable visual effects? filmed with props, digital effects, animated? Were there characters? speaking parts? a narrator? Memorable music?

Comment: The projected movie is indeed Charlie Chaplin's, and it is also called [Modern Times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Times_%28film%29)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it's this one: [MODERN TIMES](http://vimeo.com/17631561) (published in December 2010).

Ben Craig (a.k.a. [BC2010](http://vimeo.com/user4301838)) was the project's mastermind. Richard Mountney was Director of Photography, assisted by Simon Mountney, Tom Mountney and Robin Mair.

Comment: Beautiful. Right or wrong, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: u r welcome :))